# Force Jade to ignore comments inside script tag

Tags: javascript, pug

I know that commenting a line of code with `//-` will make the line invisible to Jade compiler.

It should and does work most of times, but it totally fails within `script.` tag.

For example:

```
script.
    //- this will alert!!!
    alert('test');
```

There still is the comment in the compiled code:

```
<script>
    //- this will alert!!!
    alert('test');
</script>
```

I want to keep commenting in my inline javascript code, but not letting it to the production side, how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3):

Note the dot in `script.` . The dotted block is plain text, jade syntax doesn't work there. You can have a normal block, and escape each JS line with `|`:

```
script
    //- this will alert!!!
    | alert('test');
```

but this is rather silly. Much better would be to use external scripts and minify them for production.